# Select a column from multiple dataframes in a list

Tags: r, list, subset

My list has multiple data frames with only two columns

```
DateTime       Value 
30-06-2016      100
31-07-2016      200
.
.
.
```

I just want to extract the column **Value** from the list. The fillowing code proved unsuccesful for me. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
actual_data <- lapply(test_data, function(df) df[,is.numeric(df)])
> actual_data[[1]]

data frame with 0 columns and 12 rows
```

Thank you

Comment: `lapply(test_data, '[', 2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sotos. Will you explain the solution as well ?

Comment: Try `test_data[[1]][1]` or `test_data[[2]][1]` etc..and you will get it. HINT: See how `[` is used for indexing?!

Comment: `test_data[[1]][1]` would give me the first column of the first df in the list. To be specific in my question, what does `'['` do ?

Answer (score 2):

`purrr::map` (an enhanced version of lapply) provides a shortcut for this type of operation:

```
# Generate test data
set.seed(35156)

test_df   <- data.frame('DateTime' = rnorm(100), 'Value' = rnorm(100))
test_data <- rep(list(test_df), 100)

# Use `map` from the purrr package to subset the data.frames
purrr::map(test_data, 'Value')
purrr::map(test_data, 2)
```

As you can see in the example above, you can select columns in a data.frame either by name, by passing a character string as the second argument to `purrr::map`, or by position, by passing a number.